# In vba, Loop data from different sheets vice versa

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I am learning VBA,

I have data in sheet1 18 rows with 5 columns and Sheet2 3 rows with 8 columns

I would like to loop data and print in NOTEPAD like,

- Rows 1 - 6 from sheet1 then Row 1 from sheet2
- Rows 7 - 12 from sheet1 then Row 2 from sheet2
- Row 13 - 18 from sheet1 then Row 3 from Sheet2, so on.

Here is my code,

```
Sub Looping()

Dim str As String
Dim MaxStrLen As String
Dim rest As Integer
Dim Lstr As Integer
Dim LMstr As Integer
Dim MStr As Integer
Dim LR As Range
Dim CNT As Integer

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastCol As Long
Dim LRow As Long
Dim LCol As Long
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim ws3 As Worksheet
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim Page_Break As Long
Dim k As Long
Dim PB As Long
Dim x As Long
Dim y As Long

Dim rng As Range

Set rng = Range("A1:E6")

Dim FilePath As String

Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
Set ws3 = Sheets("Sheet3")

Open "C:\Users\Antony\Music\Excel Macros\Test.txt" For Output As #2

'''''FIRST FIVE LINES WILL PRINT IN THE NOTEPAD

With ws1

LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

LRow = ws2.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
LCol = ws2.Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

BlkSize = 6            'data consists of blocks of 6 rows
For i = 1 To LastRow
sOut = vbNullString
LengthRow = i
Do While LengthRow > BlkSize
    LengthRow = LengthRow - BlkSize
Loop

'LengthRow points to row where char length is to be taken from
For j = 1 To LastCol
    str = .Cells(i, j).Value
    If str <> Empty Then
    MStr = ws2.Cells(LengthRow, j).Value
    Lstr = Len(str)
    rest = MStr - Lstr
    sOut = sOut & str & Space(rest)

    Else
    MStr = ws2.Cells(LengthRow, j).Value
    Lstr = Len(str)
    rest = MStr - Lstr
    sOut = sOut & str & Space(rest)
    End If
Next
Print #2, sOut
Next

End With

'''''LAST LINE WILL PRINT IN THE SAME NOTEPAD

With ws3
    LRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    LCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

slast = vbNullString

For k = 2 To LRow
  str = Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(.Cells(k, "A").Resize(1, LastCol).Value)), "@#")
  str = Replace(str, "=", vbNullString)

    Print #2, str
Next

Endtext = "EODR"

Print #2, slast & Endtext


End With

'Loop

Close #2

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can embed the loops:

```
For i = 0 to 2
    For j = 1 to 6
        Write Sheet1 row = i * 6 + j to file 'this line not actual code

    Next j
    Write Sheet2 row = i + 1 to file 'this line not actual code
Next i
```

Comment: I embedded, but it fails to loop in my script.

Comment: I confused sheets 1 and 2 in my example, it is fixed now.

Comment: thanks for your time in this issue., Can u share the code and embed in it., that would be great help